# Spotify - Getting Track From URI null data

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm developing a Spotify app and am getting null data in tracks I'm retrieving through `models.Track.fromURI('uri');` If I try to access any standard data on the track (eg `track.album`) I get a null reference to the variable. The only thing I seem to be able to access is `track.uri`. Oddly, outputting the track to the console shows all data is present.

This only happens on two occasions, my first calls of `models.Track.fromURI` when the app loads (reloading the app fixes the problem). And when doing the same on tracks retrieved from a search (this is the deprecated sp.core.search, so that may be the issue here).

It would appear to be an odd bug, but I can't be sure.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're waiting until the track has loaded before accessing metadata.

```
models.Track.fromURI('uri', function (track) {
    // Track has loaded!
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting a bunch of tracks at once, so a callback for one wouldn't be enough. In this situation would it make sense to check track.loaded, wait, try again?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of polling - you could add the same callback to all the tracks, perhaps?